# The nil-radical is an intersection of all prime ideals proof

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Every proof I found online made the same implications.
Take one for example:
https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Nilradical

I'm quoting the relevant part, which confuses me:

"To show the converse, it suffices to show that for any non-nilpotent element $a$, there is some prime ideal that does not contain $a$.

So suppose that $a$ is an element of $A$ that is not nilpotent. Let $S$ be the set of ideals of $A$ that do not contain any element of the form $a^n$. Since $(0) \in S$, $S$ is not empty; then by Zorn's Lemma, $S$ has a maximal element $\mathfrak{m}$.

It suffices to show that $\mathfrak{m}$ is a prime ideal. Indeed, suppose otherwise; then there exist elements $x,y \notin \mathfrak{m}$ for which $xy \in \mathfrak{m}$. Then the set of elements $z$ for which $xz \in \mathfrak{m}$ is evidently an ideal of $A$ that properly contains $\mathfrak{m}$; it therefore contains $a^n$, for some integer $n$. By similar reasoning, the set of elements $z$ for which $a^n$ $z \in \mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal that properly contains $\mathfrak{m}$, so this set contains $a^m$, for some integer $m$. Then $a^{n+m} \in \mathfrak{m}$, a contradiction.

Therefore $\mathfrak{m}$ is a prime ideal that does not contain $a$."

And then they conclude that if $a$ is not in the maximal element in $A$, and it is indeed prime, then $a$ is not in the intersection of all prime ideals,
but who said there isn't some **other** prime ideal $P$ that is not in $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by "some other prime ideal that is not in $A$"?

Comment: $A$ is the set of all ideals that do not contains $a^n$ $\forall n>0$, but way can't it be that there is some prime ideal not in $A$? meaning some prime ideal $P\notin A$, s.t. $a^n$ is indeed in $P$?

Comment: I think what you miss is that you are taking an intersection, so it suffices to have just one prime not containing $a$.

Comment: Great! that what I was missing. thanks.

Comment: I think you meant that $S$ (not $A$) is the set of all ideals that do not contain $a^n$ for all $n > 0$.

Answer (score 40):

Instead of commenting on this proof, which is too complicated in my opinion, here is a fast proof.

Assume that $a$ is not nilpotent. Then the localization $A_a$ is non-zero (otherwise $1/1=0$ in $A_a$, which would mean $a^n \cdot 1 =0$ for some $n$). Hence, it has a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. The preimage in $A$ is a prime which doesn't contain $a$ (otherwise $\mathfrak{p}$ would contain a unit). Hence, $a$ is not contained in the intersection of all prime ideals of $A$.

Comment: You are just rephraseing the proof. $A_a$ has a prime ideal is again an application of Zorn, taking a maximal ideal. The original proof given by OP is nothing more than this except it is carried out in $A$. Ideals in $A$ not containing a power of $a$ are the same as proper ideals in $A_a$.

Comment: Yes, I know all that. But you don't need to know the classification of prime ideals (your classification of ideals is not correct, by the way), and don't have to apply Zorn's Lemma to a special set of ideals, show that the maximal element is prime, and actually don't have to compute anything. It is just a combination of well-known facts (for example that any commutative ring $\neq 0$ has a prime ideal, and that prime ideals pull back along homomorphisms). When one tries to avoid $A_a$, everything gets more complicated. That beind said, "my" proof is not just a rephrasement.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I'm late to the party, but why should there be a prime ideal in $A_a$, is this meant to be Zorn (maximal=>prime)? If $0$ is the maximal ideal delivered by Zorn, the proof still works, right? The ring $A_a$ itself is the localisation at $\{1,a,a^2,\dots\}$ I assume?

Comment: Every non-trivial ring has a maximal ideal, hence a prime ideal.