# Proof verification: prime ideals in Boolean rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, boolean-ring

This question have been answered many times but I didn't find a similar proof, I submit it here for verification.

> Let $R$ be a Boolean ring (i.e. $\forall r\in R, \exists n>1: r^n=r$).
> Prove that every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal.

**Proof**:
Let $\mathfrak p\in \operatorname{Spec} R$. Suppose $\exists \mathfrak m\in \operatorname{Spec} R: \mathfrak p\subsetneq \mathfrak m \subsetneq R$.

We work in the quotient space $R/\mathfrak m$ and we denote $\overline x$ the class of $x \in R$.

Let $x\in \mathfrak m \setminus \mathfrak p$.

We have $x^n=x \implies \overline{x}^n=\overline x = \overline 0 $.

Hence $\overline x \in \operatorname{Nilp}(R/\mathfrak m) = \bigcap\limits_{\overline {\mathfrak p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak m)}\overline{\mathfrak p} = \bigcap\limits_{ \mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}R} \mathfrak p/\mathfrak m$.
This is a contradiction since $x\not\in \mathfrak p$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you for your help, I am suspecting an error in the last line.

**Edit**

In the last line, the first equality comes from the fact that the [nilradical is the intersection of all prime ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859390/the-nil-radical-is-an-intersection-of-all-prime-ideals-proof).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient ring over a maximal ideal is a field.

About your proof. It is strange. For example you take $x$ from the maximal ideal and then prove that it is $0$ in the factor-ring. And the last three lines seem to be incorrect. What is the spectrum of a field?

Comment: Good point! the spectrum of a field is just a point!

Comment: So what are you doing in the last three lines of the question?

Comment: Please check my edit for the first equality. It is tautological in this case as the intersection is over one element (as we work in a field). I have a doubt for the second equality: $\bigcap\limits_{\overline {\mathfrak p} \in \operatorname{Spec}(R/\mathfrak m)}\overline{\mathfrak p} = \bigcap\limits_{ \mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}R} \mathfrak p/\mathfrak m
$

Comment: That equality is false. The LHS is $\{0\}$ and the RHS does not make sense if $\mathfrak p$ does not contain $\mathfrak m$.

Comment: Indeed thank you!